# all in one sharing framework for Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to implement sharing functionality for at least facebook, tweeter and email.
I am using Xcode 4.5. I found Sharekit and when add classes into project got ARC errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIActivityViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) new in iOS 6 does this for you. You simply specify input text/image and present the controller, and you can share to Facebook, Twitter, Email, SMS, etc...

Quoting [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Facebook_Integration_Tutorial_using_UIActivityViewController):

```
- (IBAction)sendPost:(id)sender {
    NSArray *activityItems;

    if (_postImage.image != nil) {
        activityItems = @[_postText.text, _postImage.image];
    } else {
        activityItems = @[_postText.text];
    }

    UIActivityViewController *activityController =
                    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                    initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                    applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityController
                   animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works.
But what if someone have ios 5 installed?
My project targets for ios 6.

Answer (score 0):

Sharekit is not yet build for ARC. Your options are to turn off ARC, fix the errors/warnings, or not use sharekit and use the built in Apple APIs for Facebook, Twitter, and Email.